# How to compare two homography matrices?

Tags: matrix, projection, homography, metric

I have given two homography matrices and need to find out whether they describe (nearly) the same projection. Is there a metric which i can use for this problem?

Comment: I'm also looking for the answer, please kindly let me know if you get the answers.:)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do is to calculate the difference between `pi_a` and `pi_b`, where:

```
pi_a = Ha * ei
pi_b = Hb * ei
```

`Ha` and `Hb` are the homography matrix and `ei` are basis vectors

Comment: How do I find `ei`?

Comment: for a 3 dimensions matrix H, e0 = (1, 0, 0), e1 = (0, 1, 0), e2 = (0, 0, 1).

Comment: @MajorTom calculate the difference and what? Should it be close to 0? I mean should `p0_a - p0_b`, `p1_a - p1_b` and `p2_a - p2_b` be minimal ?

Comment: If `Ha` and `Hb` describe (nearly) the same transformation then `p0_a` must be close to `p0_b`, so yes,  you want `p0_a - p0_b` to be close to zero.